# Operation between ndarray and heterogeneous ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been trying to come uo with a way to add these two ndarrays, one of them with a different amount of elements in each row:

```
a = np.array([np.array([0, 1]), np.array([4, 5, 6])])
z = np.zeros((3,3))
```

Expected output:

```
array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```

Can anyone think of a way to do this using `numpy`?

Comment: See if this helps: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html#numpy.put_along_axis

Comment: Will look into it thx @daniel

Comment: Hmm looks like you need to know the length of each row in order to provide the correct indices, so you can't insert the arrays directly. Nice to know about this though

Comment: Looks like there's no way around this without knowing the length of each row in `a`...

Comment: It seems that way

Comment: Do you know before hand the length of the largest array?

Comment: No, but one can do `len(max(a, key = len))`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a 'numpy-fast' solution for this. I think you will need to loop over `a` with a for loop and add every line individually.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    z[i,:len(a[i])] = z[i,:len(a[i])] + a[i]
```

Comment: Posted too early, sorry. Added the text with my edit.